# Python 3: try/except not working. Am I misunderstanding something here?

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-except

I'm new to Python and wanted to try out its exception by a simple dividing function, but the program still crashed and did not catch "Denominator cannot be 0" in the terminal. Any explanation would be great. Thank you!

---

```py
try:
    def divide(num, deno):
        return num / deno
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print('Denominator cannot be 0')

result = int(divide(6, 0))
print(result)
```

---

Expecting the terminal to print out 'Denominator cannot be 0' instead of 'ZeroDevisionError'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exceptions are raised *when the function is called* not when the function is *defined*.

So you need:

```
def divide(num, deno):
    return num / deno

try:
    result = int(divide(6, 0))
    print(result)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print('Denominator cannot be 0')
```

Of course, you are going to have to take care since your `result` variable will only be defined if `divide` doesn't raise the exception. But this is the simplest way to modify your code to show you how this *could* work.